# ObjectMapper not considering annotations

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

I have the below piece of code which would convert an annotated Java object into Json String.

```
 try {
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            LOGGER.debug("logAsJson", jsonString);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("logAsJson", "Exception in logging only. Nothing critical! ", e);
        }
```

And my class would look something like this

public class Car {

```
@JsonProperty("capabilities")
private List<Capability> capability = new ArrayList<Capability>();

@JsonProperty("periodicity")
@NotNull
private Periodicity periodicity;

@JsonProperty("car_driver")
private List<carDriver> carDriver = new ArrayList<carDriver>();
```

}

Problem is that while creating the json string from the object, object mapper is not considering the annotations for field names.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if you have jackson 1 and jackson 2 in your classpath, and if you're using mapper from one version and annotations from the other one.

Comment: That was my thought also, check the annotation you are using matches the library you are using.

Comment: That worked Guys, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Ajay How did you fixed this issue ?. I am also facing the same prob

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might have imported the json annotation and the object mapper from different library versions. Make sure they are from the same library.

Example,

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;`

and

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Kotlin, I thought the use of annotations was enabled by default, but apparently not, and this solved the problem:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MapperFeature
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
...
val objectMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS, true)
...
val json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj)
```